# How to write variable in docker-compose, running multiple containers which uses the same image but their ports are different

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use docker-compose to maintain containers, there is a cluster of API servers.

They build from the same image, I knew the `docker-compose scale app=5` will start 5 containers, but they all same, including port setting.

I want to run multiple containers like this:

```
services:

  # wx_service_cluster

  wx_service_51011:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/wx_service
    ports:
      - "51011:8080"

  wx_service_51012:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      volumes:
        - .:/go/src/wx_service
      ports:
        - "51012:8080"

  wx_service_...:
      ....
      THERE ARE ALMOST 100 SERVICES NEED TO BE WROTE
      ANYONE CAN HELPS ME TO MAKE IT SIMPLER.
```

can I make it simpler?

like a shell loop:

```
for each_port in $( seq 51011 51040 )
{
    wx_service_${each_port}:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      volumes:
        - .:/go/src/wx_service
      ports:
        - "${each_port}:8080"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer to your actual questions: Use ENV variables and probably combine it with dotenv https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

```
services:
  foo_{$instance1}
    ports:
      - "${instance1}:8080"
  foo_{$instance12}
    ports:
      - "${instance2}:8080"
```

but this will not help you "generating a docker-compose file with X service entries for WX" .. you seem to plan some kind of "hosting".

#### Alternatives:

You should step back, and rather use random-port assignment and the use docker inspect to find the port - see an example here https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/blob/master/lib/docker-sync/sync_strategy/unison.rb#L199 .. so basically you either use a template system to generate you docker-compose.yml file - e.g. like https://github.com/markround/tiller .. then you generate services with a static prefix like wx_service_ .. and later you use a different script ( for you nginx / haproxy ) to configure and upstream for each of those, find the name and port (using inspect) dynamically.

If i am right and you really go for some kind of hosting scenario and you do it commercially - you might even rethink this and add consul to the game. Let every wx service register as a service in consul and then use a additional httpd passenger like nginx / haproxy to reconfigure itself and add a backend+frontend/upstream+server entry in the passender using tiller+`consul watch`.

The last one is just the next level stuff, but if you do that "commercially" you should not do what you asked for initially - nevertheless, if you choose to, use dotenv as outlined above